# Is AVX intrinsic _mm256_cmp_ps supposed to return NaN when true?

Tags: c++, simd, avx

When i try:

```
__m256 a = _mm256_set_ps(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
__m256 b = _mm256_set_ps(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

__m256 c = _mm256_cmp_ps(a, b, _CMP_LT_OQ);
```

Which is a < b I get the output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

But when trying:

```
__m256 a = _mm256_set_ps(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
__m256 b = _mm256_set_ps(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

__m256 c = _mm256_cmp_ps(b, a, _CMP_LT_OQ);
```

or

```
__m256 a = _mm256_set_ps(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
__m256 b = _mm256_set_ps(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

__m256 c = _mm256_cmp_ps(a, b, _CMP_GT_OQ);
```

I get

```
[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
```

is this expected behaviour? The documentation at https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524077 just says that it returns the result without specifying.

Comment: The result is all 1s, for true, which happens to be a NaN. For false it's all 0s, which happens to be 0.0. Typically you use the result as a bitwise mask, so the float value isn't really meaningful.

Comment: What does the macro do: "_CMP_LE_OQ", what is the difference between OQ and OS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the returned value is a bitmask: it is set to all zeroes for false, or all ones for true. 32 bits of ones happen to be encoding of NaN when interpreted as a 32-bit float.

Bitmasks are useful because you can use them to mask out some results, e.g. `(A & M) | (B & ~M)` will select the value of `A` when the mask `M` was true (all ones) and the value of `B` when the mask was false (all zeroes).